# Usage of transition words

Tags: grammar, adverbs, adverb-position

Consider the following portion from a drug's website:

*Bamocaftor potassium is a CFTR channel (DeltaF508-CFTR Mutant) corrector in phase II clinical trials at Vertex, in patients with CF who are homozygous for the F508del mutation of the CF transmembrane conductance regulator (CFTR) gene, or who are heterozygous for the F508del mutation and a minimal function (MF) CFTR mutation not likely to respond to tezacaftor, ivacaftor, or tezacaftor/ivacaftor and also in combination with tezacaftor and VX-561 in F508del/MF in patients with cystic fibrosis.*

*The compound is also developed by the company as a fixed-dose combination of VX-659, tezacaftor and ivacaftor.*

Can the two separate portions be merged to form something like:

*Bamocaftor potassium is a CFTR channel (DeltaF508-CFTR Mutant) corrector in phase II clinical trials at Vertex, in patients with CF who are homozygous for the F508del mutation of the CF transmembrane conductance regulator (CFTR) gene, or who are heterozygous for the F508del mutation and a minimal function (MF) CFTR mutation not likely to respond to tezacaftor, ivacaftor, or tezacaftor/ivacaftor and also in combination with tezacaftor and VX-561 in F508del/MF in patients with cystic fibrosis. **Furthermore, the compound is also developed by the company as a fixed-dose combination of VX-659, tezacaftor and ivacaftor**.*

Does it make sense to connect the two portions, or should I have just left it as it is? And is "also" redundant when the sentence already starts with "furthermore"?

Comment: I'd say it's only retrievable using bullet points. Probably with subdivisions (1; 2a, 2b ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you suggesting that merging both would not be the correct way to go about it?

Comment: My two degrees are in chemistry, and I can't decipher your first paragraph. Suggesting whether or not to connect a second portion seems moot.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If I choose not to connect a second portion, does the original form seem to be in flow?

Comment: @MileZero I know almost nothing about chemistry, but I do know the first paragraph—which is actually a single sentence—is a terrible example of writing. Yes, you can make it a single paragraph. No, that would not help it in any way. What I would suggest is dropping everything after *trials at Vertex* and adding the second sentence to form a paragraph. Then take the text that was dropped, and turn it into a second paragraph, ideally with at least three sentences.